# mkdir using variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, bash-expansion

I am having issues creating dirs using a variable in a script. Ex:

```
read user
mkdir $user{01..10}
```

Interestingly, it will work like this:

```
read user
mkdir {01..10}$user
```

Any way to get around this, or what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion happens before variable expansion in `bash`.  This means that the command

```
mkdir $user{01..10}
```

is first expanded to

```
mkdir $user01 $user02 (etc.)
```

These variables does not exist, so the final command that is run will be

```
mkdir
```

with no operands.

To fix this, use

```
mkdir "$user"{01..10}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use brackets make the right variable expansion and environment variable resolving:

```
read user
mkdir ${user}{01..10}
```

Double quotes although isn't the most elegant way, still works:

```
read user
mkdir "$user"{01..10}
```